# operator << overloading for vector of objects

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, ostream

everybody.

I have a class called "Card" and "CardDeck" where the second is a vector, which contains many cards of the first class.

My << overloading goes like this:

```
istream& operator<<(ostream& os, Card& card) {
    string str;
    if(cardValueCorrect(card._value)){
        str += to_string(card._value);
    } else {
        str += card._identier;
    }
    str += suitToChar(card._suit);
    return os << str;
```

And that I think should be fine, at least the compiler doesnt complain about this. The trouble starts when in my CardDeck I want to overload << so it would print all the cards are in.

```
CardDeck << overloading seems like that: 
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CardDeck& odeck){
    for(const Card cur_card: odeck._Deck){
        os << cur_card << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}
```

It complains about accessing to private fields of card and also:

```
invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream<char>&}' from expression of type 'std::basic_ostream<char>'
```

and then other very strange stuff as (about **each line** in the first operator overloading):

```
within this context
```

**EDIT**

**istream to ostream** fixed.

That was one probem. Now I see 162 warrnings with "info" about the CardDeck operator overloading and it tell's me i'm **getting to private fields of CardDeck** (the vector is there).

**Eather:**

```
`invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'CardDeck&' from an rvalue of type no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'const Card')`
```

and a lot of "info" (eclipse) of such repeating pattern:

```
'const Card' is not derived from 'const std::extreme_value_distribution<_RealType>'
```

Comment: You really should be passing `const Card&` and `const CardDeck&` to `operator <<`.

Comment: Generally, the overloaded operator is declared as a friend inside a class:  `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Card& card);` This *friendship* allows the freestanding operator<< function to access the `Card` private and protected members.

Comment: BTW, having class name and variable name only differ by case is a poor practice.  Consider the problems when typo's occur.  The usual coding guideline is to have variable names differ from class names by more than case.

Comment: made it const, still have the deck private error

Comment: seems to be the problem is in the second overloading (of CardDeck), because if I put it in comment, no errors.

Comment: and another problem as you said is "allows the freestanding operator<< function to access the Card private and protected members.". But that is something I want for this operator, am I not ?

Comment: Ok, I found all the mistakes, they were minor. It is the hour. thank you to everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
istream& operator<<(ostream& os, Card& card)
```

with

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Card& card)
```

Comment: I've edited the question above according to that problem (one of many).